# Ubuntu 17.10 crashes quite often

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, gpu

I have recently updated my ubuntu to 17.10.It was working fine for a while.But I wanted to install Tensor flow.So, I installed nouveau.After doing so,It keeps on crashing randomly 10 times a day.I tried to do all the fixes suggested online to run nvidia gpu like disable of wayland.etc
https://charlienewey.github.io/getting-nvidia-drivers-working-on-ubuntu-17-10/

But still the problem exists.Is there a way can i uninstall my nvidia driver or degrade my ubuntu to lower version.Please, help me here....

Comment: What was "my gpu driver" before, and what is it now. How did you update it?

Comment: Sorry I didnot update it...I installed nouveau

Comment: If you are using laptop try bumblebee "sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic"

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: happy republic day

Comment: My Ubuntu 17.1 keeps freezes or crashes 10 times a day....It X.org issue I am not able to solve it...I tried all the steps posted in internet still the problem persists.....Please help me out in this regard....

Comment: Fixed the issue.....The problem was with my graphic card.....I uninstalled my Graphics driver.........Every works fine....

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with my Graphics card. Everytime If I open an application that uses graphics card it went on a freeze. I uninstalled my Graphics driver all together.I am working with intel graphics.Now everything works fine.

Comment: Actually after I installed Gnome everything worked fine with graphics driver.